# How can I use RMAN to show if there are archive logs that need to backed up?

Tags: oracle, backup, transaction-log, archive-log

My main concern is knowing if the Oracle Archive Logs haven't been backed up in a while because something is broken that I may not know about.

When I query v$log it appears to be good with First_Time being very recent.  I would think v$log wouuld have lots of rows if the logs had not been backing up.

```
SELECT * FROM v$log;
```

Shows only a few, two say current (four returned).

```
select * from v$log_history order by FIRST_TIME desc;
```

Shows lots.

Comment: @Balazs Papp gave you the correct technical answer.  But I'm wondering how it is you don't know that your backup jobs are broken.  The very first thing I do every morning is scan the log files of my overnight backup jobs.

Comment: I wear many hats.

Comment: "I wear many hats." - So?  if, as the very fact that you posted this question suggests, you are responsible for the backups (and by extension, recovery), then part of that responsibility is monitoring the success of the jobs, not to allow "something" to get broken without noticing.  I don't mean to be argumentative about your job, but ask yourself this: If the database gets corrupted and needs to be recovered from backup - cannot be recovered because it was not noticed that backup jobs were failing - whose feet are going to be held to the fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from RMAN.

```
list archivelog all backed up 0 times to disk;
```

or

```
list archivelog all backed up 0 times to sbt_tape;
```

Depending on the backup method you use.

Comment: is there any way to get the list using queries from V$ARCHIVED_LOG and V$BACKUP_ARCHIVELOG_SUMMARY.

Answer (score 2):

You can query v$archived_log

```
SELECT  *
FROM    V$ARCHIVED_LOG
WHERE   ARCHIVED != 'YES';
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following query:

```
select THREAD#, count(SEQUENCE#), min(SEQUENCE#), max(SEQUENCE#)  
from v$loghist  
where FIRST_CHANGE# >=   
    (select MAX_NEXT_CHANGE#  
     from V$BACKUP_ARCHIVELOG_SUMMARY)  
group by THREAD#;
```

My issue with the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188022/6219) is that I also get the archive log already backed up once.  The `v$archived_log`, on the other hand, only states that the redo-log is archived, but not that it's backed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can query some internal Oracle tables/views directly to retrieve the information you are looking for.

I use the following statement to retrieve the information:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(MIN(bp.CREATION_TIME), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS oldest_backup_time,
  bs.SET_STAMP,
  bs.SET_COUNT
FROM
  V$BACKUP_PIECE bp
  JOIN V$BACKUP_SET bs ON bp.SET_STAMP = bs.SET_STAMP
                       AND bp.SET_COUNT = bs.SET_COUNT
WHERE
  bp.STATUS = 'A' -- Filter for available backups
GROUP BY
  bs.SET_STAMP,
  bs.SET_COUNT
ORDER BY
  oldest_backup_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `list archivelog all backed up 0 times to disk;` returns existing archive logs that have been backed up plus those that have not. So the following SQL statement uses the v$Archived_Log view and can be run from within RMAN. It lists all logs which have not been backed up yet.

```
SELECT Sequence#, Name FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG WHERE Backup_Count = 0;
```